# OpenRefine - Lost records

Tags: openrefine

I am creating a new project in OpenRefine Version 2.6-rc.2 and loading a csv file with 3185 rows. The file is small (342 KB). Everything seems to go fine (no error or malformed columns) except that I end up with 3155 records: 30 records disappeared in the load. Any ideas?

Thanks. 
Ivan

Comment: I did a test on a new project by loading the file, doing some transformation and exporting bak to csv. The resulting file as 3185 rows even though the project displays 3155 records...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like after the import OR is in 'Records' mode - you need to switch to Rows mode to see all the rows (you can do this towards top left, just above the cells).

The 'Rows' mode will give you the individual rows - and should be the same as you imported as long as everything has gone OK on import.

"Records" mode can group multiple rows together - so you may find there are less Records than there are Rows. There is a bit more explanation of Records towards the bottom of this page https://github.com/OpenRefine/OpenRefine/wiki/Variables

Comment: Thanks Owen, this answer my question. However It's not really clear for me how rows are grouped into records when applicable. The example in the doc is too simple.

Comment: You may find the following links helpful in understanding rows vs records in OpenRefine: [http://kb.refinepro.com/2012/03/difference-between-record-and-row.html](http://kb.refinepro.com/2012/03/difference-between-record-and-row.html) [https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=183&v=NnCA1dnCT-c](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=183&v=NnCA1dnCT-c)